# Overlay xyplot on levelplot with common x axis in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, lattice

Suppose I have these two data-sets:

```
dat <- data.frame("year"= c(2000:2005),"X1"=runif(6,-3,3),"X2"=runif(6,-3,3),"X3"=runif(6,-3,3),"X4"=runif(6,-3,3),"X5"=runif(6,-3,3),"X6"=runif(6,-3,3),"X7"=runif(6,-3,3),"X8"=runif(6,-3,3),"X9"=runif(6,-3,3),"X10"=runif(6,-3,3),"X11"=runif(6,-3,3),"X12"=runif(6,-3,3))

newd <- data.frame("year"=c(2000:2005), "val"=c(40,45,50,35,40,55), "sd"=c(5,6,8,4,5,9))
```

I want to plot the second data-set on the first one, so that both have the common x axis but different y axes.
Here is how I plot the first dataset using `lattice levelplot` function:

```
library(lattice)
idx <- c(1:12)
dat2 <- expand.grid(y=dat[,1], x=idx)
dat2$z <- as.vector(as.matrix(dat[,-1]))
levelplot(z ~ y*x, data=dat2)
```

[image]

I appreciate any suggestions on overlaying `newd` data, common `x=year` axis, and new `y` axis for `value` variable with standard deviation band `sd`.

Comment: is this what you want `p1 = levelplot(z ~ y*x, data=dat2) ; p2 = lattice::xyplot(val ~ year, data=newd, type="l") ; latticeExtra::doubleYScale(p1, p2, add.axis=TRUE)` (hopefully not ;))

Comment: yes, its almost there! do you know how I can have the y axis on the left side (two y axes side by side)? can I appreciate if you could tell me how to plot standard deviation band around the line using the newd$sd data?

Comment: im sure there will be a clever lattice way to do this, but why not just add extra line calls : `p2 = lattice::xyplot(val ~ year, data=newd, type="l", lwd=3, ylim=c(30, 60)) +   lattice::xyplot(I(val+sd) ~ year, data=newd, type="l") +
  lattice::xyplot(I(val-sd) ~ year, data=newd, type="l")` . I dont know how to move the axis to the lhs.

Comment: Thanks that works! could you add this into the answer section? I'm also interested to know how to have `sd` as shades.